# Application halts during/after encryption/serialisation

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization

I found a way to encrypt and serialise/de serialise an object

[C# Encrypt serialized file before writing to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869922/c-sharp-encrypt-serialized-file-before-writing-to-disk)

Here's my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Digital_Only_Calculator
{
    class EncryptionSerialiser
    {

        byte[] key = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }; // Where to store these keys is the tricky part, 
                                                 // you may need to obfuscate them or get the user to input a password each time
        byte[] iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        string path = Application.StartupPath + @"\" + "test.ser";
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();



        public void EncryptThenSerialise(object obj)
        {

            // Encryption
            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, des.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                // This is where you serialize the class
                formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, obj);

            }
        }
public Person DecryptThenSerialise(object obj)
        {
            // Decryption
            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, des.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                // This is where you deserialize the class
                Person deserialized = (Person)formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);

                return deserialized;
            }
        }
  }
}
```

And the code for testing...

```
Person p = new Person();

            p.Name = "Bill";
            p.Age = 40;


            EncryptionSerialiser ESER = new EncryptionSerialiser();
            ESER.EncryptThenSerialise(p);

            Person p2 = new Person();

            p2 = ESER.DecryptThenSerialise(p2);
```

The problem is, the application does not continue after this line (which you can see above in the EncryptThenSerialise method.

```
formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, obj);
```

Person class...

```
 public class Person
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

It does however seem to encrypt and serialise the object, as a new file is created which when opened looks encrypted. It just doesn't go on to then perform the de serialisation.

Any Ideas anyone?

Comment: "the application does not continue after this line" Does it hang, or does it crash?

Comment: It seems to "Break", i.e. exits from the method and allows user to use controls forms etc. So it's almost like it 'thinks' it has finished but it has not.

Answer (score 0):

I added the  [Serializable] attribute to my Person Class. All working now.

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```