# System.Security.CryptpgraphicUnexpectedOperationException when creating ICryptoTransform

Tags: c#, xamarin, cryptography

I get an error: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicUnexpectedOperationException`

When I run the following:

```
DESCryptoServiceProvider dESCrypto = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
byte[] iv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var v = dESCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
```

Stacktrace:
`at Crimson.CommonCrypto.Cryptor.Create (Crimson.CommonCrypto.CCOperation operation, Crimson.CommonCrypto.CCAlgorithm algorithm, Crimson.CommonCrypto.CCOptions options, System.Byte[] key, System.Byte[] iv) [0x0005d] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.cs:99`

It is in a Xamarin project where I was hoping to use it like in the second answer in this thread [C# Encrypt serialized file before writing to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869922/c-sharp-encrypt-serialized-file-before-writing-to-disk)

How can I solve this problem?

Edit:
Using AES and 8 values instead of 9 - unfortunately creates the same exception

Comment: These days you should only use DES if you must use DES for interoperability reasons, if that's not the case you should be using AES/3DES which have far larger key spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set key/IV size 9 bytes, but DES can only work with 8 bytes. Change it to something like below:

```
DESCryptoServiceProvider dESCrypto = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
byte[] iv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var v = dESCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
```